# Rails/Ckeditor howto change height?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ckeditor, simple-form

This may seem very stpd,sorry ...; rails4 /ckeditor/simpleform: somehow the body of a f.ckeditor text-area gets a style="height:200px", and I just can't find out where to change that size? Anyone a hint? thnx!

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this in js where you init your ckeditor.

For example

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function (config) {
  // ... other configuration ...

  config.toolbar_mini = [
    ["Bold",  "Italic",  "Underline",  "Strike",  "-",  "Subscript",  "Superscript"],
  ];
  config.toolbar = "simple";
  extraPlugins : 'uicolor',
  height: '800px',

  // ... rest of the original config.js  ...
}
```

Means that you height now is 800px.

Comment: Nope, doesn't work, neither does `rows: 50` My code (all the other vars, like te toolbar work): 
`CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function (config) {
  // configuration options
  height: '800px';
  config.toolbar = [
  { name: 'basicstyles', items: [ 'Save', 'Bold', 'Italic', 'Strike', '-', 'RemoveFormat' ] },
  { name: 'clipboard', items: [ 'Cut', 'Copy', 'Paste', 'PasteText', 'PasteFromWord', '-', 'Undo', 'Redo' ] },
  { name: 'editing', items: [ 'Scayt' ] },
  { name: 'links', items: [ 'Link', 'Unlink'] },
  { name: 'tools', items: [ 'Maximize' ] },`

Comment: Can you see this extraPlugins : 'uicolor'. I don't know why, but it fixed the problem for setting size, that's why I put it into my code example.

Comment: Another option is to use pure jQuery to set content tag of CK $('.cke_contents').css('height','800px');

Comment: I'll try the jQuery tag, but in the mean time this works:
`config.js .....

    config.extraPlugins = 'save';
    config.language = 'en';
    config.uiColor = '#B8E5FF';
    config.enterMode = CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR;
    config.height = '600px'
    `